# wpf customControl binding itemscontrol DataTemplate button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

i am new to WPF so i am stuck with some binding on my customcontrol click button.

I have textbox that has watermark and selctedItems properties. Control if selecteditems != null display them in control as this:

link to picture
[http://s29.postimg.org/p25qgqzwn/image.jpg][1]

Now i need to wire up X buttons to delete that item from selectedItems source.
I am trying to do this in OnApplyTemplate method but i dont know how to get to that button in itemscontrol to attach mouse click event.

my Xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxPicker}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultWatermarkTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedItemsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultSelectedItemsTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxPicker}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PART_WatermarkHost"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Watermark}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Border>

                    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="PART_SelectedItemsHost"
                                ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding SelectedItems}"
                                ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectedItemsTemplate}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                                                                      
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Visibility="Visible">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>

                    </Border>
                </Grid>
               ....
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

and my ItemTemplate is looking like this

xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultSelectedItemsTemplate" >
    <Border x:Name="selectedItemBorder" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Margin="5,1,1,1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Ime}" Margin="5,0,3,0"></TextBlock>-->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,3,0"></TextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="PART_selectedItemButton" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" >X</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

.cs code

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        ItemsControl selectedItem = GetTemplateChild("PART_SelectedItemsHost") as ItemsControl;

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            selectedItem.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(selectedItemBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown);

            // blind click on X buttons in ItemsControl
        }

    }
```

so how can i bind click on that "X" button on items in code-behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the viewmodel with the ObservableCollection and the Command that will execute the X:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    public ObservableCollection<String> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Command<String> DeleteItem
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<string>((item) =>
            {
                if (items.Contains(item))
                {
                    items.Remove(item);
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
            });
        }
    }
```

Now the XAML:

Resources, where it is binded to the 'parent' datacontext, this is a easy way to know where the binding is going:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultSelectedItemsTemplate" >
        <Border x:Name="selectedItemBorder" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5"  Margin="5,1,1,1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Ime}" Margin="5,0,3,0"></TextBlock>-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,3,0"></TextBlock>
                <Button x:Name="PART_selectedItemButton" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItem, ElementName=ItemsControlInstance}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">X</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

And finally the itemscontrol:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlInstance" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultSelectedItemsTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Comment: hmm i dont know how to implement your code .. i have my customControl cs and generic xaml where is my style with templates. ( i have public properties SelectedItems (IEnumerable) but that Command<string> part i dont understand and what is Elementname = ItemsControlInstance (i can put my entire solution file if it is needed)

Comment: this code doesnt work for me public Command<String> DeleteItem ... do i need som usings or references becouse i never saw Command with <string> type

Comment: The ItemsControl is <ItemsControl x:Name="PART_SelectedItemsHost"
replace ItemsControlInstance with  PART_SelectedItemsHost

Answer (score 0):

Finally i manage to make it work, with help and guidance from Jaun it still didnt work (i tried probably 10 different things and it was in DataContext .. it was never binded.

So on my override OnApplyTemplate i added this.DataContext = this ... so i missed that part.

I used AttachedCommandBehavior (nuget) for command

code:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.DataContext = this;

        ItemsControl itmControl = GetTemplateChild("PART_SelectedItemsHost") as ItemsControl;

        if (itmControl != null)
        {
            itmControl.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(itmControl_MouseLeftButtonDown);

            // blind click on X buttons in ItemsControl
        }

    }
```