# How to read objects from list and bind every object to a button in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

i am making some application and i need to get all objects from List and bind every object for it's personal button. 
I want to make as many buttons as there are objects in that list.
Can that be done in WPF?

Comment: And i guess i need to initialize that list in mainwindow xaml cs?
(Not experienced in WPF :) )

Comment: I think this answer is just about an exact match: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874527/424129

Comment: Yes, using an ItemsControl in your view, an observable collection holding your objects in your view model, and a data template for what the buttons should look like in your views resources.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look

Comment: Your question is mostly just too broad, and shows zero evidence of having done any research, never mind of making any attempt to write code to solve your problem. However, the marked duplicate is one example of many that would seem to relate exactly to your question (it actually has a little extra functionality you may or may not need, but it shows clearly how to address your stated goal).